# (Wordpress) Contact Form 7 abort in before_send_mail filter

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, filter, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 as a mailing system on my WordPress website. I use the wpcf7_before_send_mail filter to send all the data to an external webservice (SOAP). When I receive a "SUCCESS" message of that webservice, all should continue as normal, but when I receive a "FAILED" message, contact form 7 shouldn't send out an email and a different output message should appear on the website. Is it possible to alter this within the function?

```
<?

 add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
 add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_css', '__return_false' );

 add_action('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_soap_service');


//Pushen via SOAP service naar servers
function wpcf7_soap_service($contact_form) {
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission ) {

/*** POST variabelen ***/    
$posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();

/*** SOAP settings ***/    
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

/*** variabelen opzetten ***/
define('BROADCAST_URL','XXX');
define('SIM_LOGIN', 'XXX');
define('SIM_PASSWORD', 'XXX');
define('ENV_KEY', 'XXX');

/*** login parameters ***/
$params = array(
  'username' => SIM_LOGIN,
  'password' => SIM_PASSWORD,
  'environmentKey' => ENV_KEY,
);

/*** client opzetten ***/
$client = new SoapClient(
  BROADCAST_URL,
  array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
  )
);

/*** Parameters ***/
$address["box"]           = $posted_data["box"];
$address["country"]       = $posted_data["country"];
$address["number"]        = $posted_data["streetnumber"];
$address["postalcode"]    = $posted_data["postalcode"];
$address["street"]        = $posted_data["street"];
$address["town"]          = $posted_data["town"];

$birthdate                = $posted_data["birthdate"] . "T00:00:00";
$email                    = $posted_data["email"];

$firstname                = $posted_data["firstname"];
$lastname                 = $posted_data["lastname"];
$phone                    = $posted_data["phone"];

/*** STDClass aanmaken met gevraagde data ***/
$std = new stdClass();

$std->Firstname           = $firstname;
$std->Lastname            = $lastname;
$std->Birthdate           = $birthdate;
$std->Phone               = $phone;
$std->Email               = $email;

$std->Address = new stdClass();

$std->Address->Street         = $address["street"];
$std->Address->Number         = $address["number"];
$std->Address->Box            = $address["box"];
$std->Address->PostalCode     = $address["postalcode"];
$std->Address->Town           = $address["town"];
$std->Address->Country        = $address["country"];

if(!empty($_FILES['cv'])){

    $std->Files = new stdClass();

    $std->Files->File["FileName"]     = $_FILES["cv"]["name"];
    $std->Files->File["DataFile"]     = base64_encode($_FILES["cv"]["tmp_name"]);
    $std->Files->File["FileType"]     = "CV";
}

/*** Functie OpenSession ***/
try{
  $token = $client->OpenSession($params);
}catch(SoapFault $ex){
  // ABORT OVER HERE
}

$token                = $token->OpenSessionResult;

/*** Functie AddApplication ***/
try{
  $result = $client->AddApplication(array("token" => $token, "application" => $std));
}catch(SoapFault $ex){
  // ABORT OVER HERE
}

if($result->AddApplicationResult->Status == "Success"){
  // ABORT OVER HERE
}


/*** Functie CloseSession ***/
try{
  $app = $client->CloseSession($token);
}catch(SoapFault $ex){
  // ABORT OVER HERE
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can skip the mail by using:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail',  '__return_true' );
```

Since you've disabled the javascript with

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_load_js', '__return_false' );
```

then you can use:

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'wpse_form_response_output', 10, 4 );
```

within your `wpcf7_before_send_mail` action callback, where your custom error response is:

```
function wpse_form_response_output( $output, $class, $content, $object )
{
    return sprintf(
        '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" 
            role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>',
        __( 'SOAP ERROR - Mail not sent!' )
    );
}
```

Comment: You missed a comma after the div in your function, but with that it works perfectly. Would you mind showing me where you found this information? I'd like to learn instead of just copy-paste.

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you, thanks for the typo correction. Sure, I just worked through the source code of that plugin, I  tried various ideas, this one worked, other's didn't. So there was no magic at work here, other than  spending *time* with a dash of manual test labour ;-) @WarreBuysse

Comment: I keep on bumping against the same problem, not truly understanding the source code I guess. Thanks for the explanation. It, obviously, worked out perfectly. I'll accept your answer. Thanks again!